# Moving content from one workbook to the another without opening it

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have excel sheet (1) in workbook A which update the DATA in designated cells when launch.
I want cells content to appear in another excel sheet (1) of workbook B in NEXT row witout opening it.
Basically, trying to log content of sheet (1) workbook A to sheet (1) workbook B.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a reference to a cell in another workbook, and you open that workbook, excel will ask you if you want to update the values. You do not have to open the first workbook for it. If that isn't what you're after it isn't possible.